# Synchronous XMLHttRequest error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

Below is my script. I am using codeigniter, a php framework along with jquery and ajax. The task is to add employee details to the database through ajax, but I am getting this error:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help
>   http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

```
    <script>
    $(function(){

        $('#btnAdd').click(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('Add New Employee');
        $('#empForm').attr('action','<?php echo base_url() ?>addEmployee')
    });


    $('#btnSave').click(function(){
        var url = $('#empForm').attr('action');
        var data = $('#empForm').serialize();


    //Validations
       var empName = $('input[name="emp_name"]');
       var empAdd = $('input[name="emp_address"]');
       var result ='';
       if(empName.val()==''){
           empName.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
       }
       else{
           empName.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
           result +='1';
       }

       if(empAdd.val()==''){
           empAdd.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
       }
       else{
           empAdd.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
           result +='2';
       }
      if(result=='12'){
          $.ajax({
          type : 'ajax',
          method : 'post',
          url :url,
          data : data,
          async : false,
          dataType : 'json',
          success: function(success){
              if(response.success){
                   $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                   $('#empForm')[0].reset();
                   index();
              }
              else{
                  alert('error');
              }
        },
        error: function(){
               alert('Could Not Add Data');
        }
     });
  }
});
```

Comment: If btnSave is a submit button, you need to change your script to `$("#empForm").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var url = $(this).attr('action');....` and REMOVE   async : false,

Comment: With **async : false** property on your ajax request you are making your request syncronized. That means whole application will freeze till the data set into your end. Remove that property or set it to true. (Its true by default)

Comment: I don't even understand why jQuery allows to set `async:false` in the first place. Every rookie in the world set it fo `false` because they can.

Comment: $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, original_Options, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
});      Will this code solve my problem?

Comment: I have added this code and also removed async:false now the problem is the records are being stored in database but at first when i click the save button it show 'Could not add data'.But, after I refresh the page it does get added to the databases. Can you tell me where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because your Ajax request in synchronous (`asyc: false`).

The error even give you a link where you can read more about it..

`Throws an InvalidAccessError exception if async is false`

Ref: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method

To resolve your problem you should either set async to true or don't specify it at all.

Comment: Already in the comments. Let's have the delete the question as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 0):

The work around (async:true) would be showing a loading image and in success hide the loading image.

Using async:false is not recommended as it stops all the js actions and stands still for the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

> type : 'ajax',

type should be a GET or POST and should be used only if your jquery version is < 1.9.1

> async : false,

you dont need to change the "asynch" behaviour, because, after all the first letter in Ajax stands for "asynchronous"

Comment: Thank You for your reply. But, i have set 'method:post' already.